# Hidden WebDAV folders not hidden when mounted in Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav

Is there a specific setting for Apache to hide folders that are not readable by the current user?
While i'm well aware this feature is perfectly working when using a Browser to list directories, it unfortunately isn't when a user performs the same task using the Windows feature. All non-readable folders are listed, and can at least be accessed - though its not possible to read or write to them.